# Wordpress Database String unserialize PHP

Tags: php, string, wordpress, serialization

In wordpress i use the plugin Pie-register, to have a more custom user registration. It writes the adress in the database. 
The string is like:

```
a:6:{s:7:"address";s:12:"Street Street";s:8:"address2";s:2:"25";s:4:"city";s:5:"Cologne";s:5:"state";s:7:"Germany";s:3:"zip";s:5:"25125";s:7:"country";s:7:"Germany";}
```

Also I tried to use Online Tools like http://i-tools.org/unserialize to unserialize the string, but the cant handle it..

unserialize doesnt work.. Do you have any suggestions how i can get the data ? :O Thanks.. :)

Comment: the string is corrupted. "Street Street" is **13** characters, but `s:12` says it's only 12. Something's trashed this string, and you'd be better off fixing whatever's causing the corruption instead of try to compensate for it. Ditto for "Cologne"

Comment: @MarcB And Cologne being 7 as opposed to 5.

Comment: Sorry, just changed the street name, cause it was my real one.. a:4:{s:7:"address";s:13:"Street Street";s:4:"city";s:7:"Cologne";s:3:"zip";s:5:"50767";s:7:"country";s:7:"Germany";} doesnt work..